# How to delete objects from array by list of IDs in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects that have specific IDs and another second array of objects that also have specified IDs. I want to delete objects from the first array that have the same ID as objects in the second array. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you're using and the code you've tried?

Comment: For example: array=[{id:1,name:'abc'},{id:2,name:'def'}]\

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [edit] your question post to include a plain-text self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when someone pastes it into a standalone IDE. Ideally you'd also show or describe what you've already tried.

Comment: Please edit your question with this new info and include both arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you're trying to do?

```js
let arr1 = [{
  id: 0,
  name: 'x'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'y'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'z'
}];

const arr2 = [{
  id: 0,
  name: 'x'
}];

arr1 = arr1.filter(element => !arr2.find(el => el.id === element.id));

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that seems to fit what you are trying to accomplish.

[How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question as asked.  The OP is apparently asking how to filter an array, not merge arrays.  Even if this were applicable, a link-only answer is fairly low quality and if it points to Stack Overflow then really you might be better off voting to close the question as  a duplicate instead of posting an answer.  Could you either edit or remove this answer to improve its quality?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this requirement with the help of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with the [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1
}, {
    id: 2
}, {
    id: 3
}, {
    id: 4
}, {
    id: 5
}];

const arr2 = [{
    id: 2
}, {
    id: 3
}, {
    id: 5
}];

const res = arr1.filter(obj => !arr2.map(({ id }) => id).includes(obj.id));

console.log(res);
```